# How to avoid our program being crashed because a DLL it has dynamically loaded is buggy

Tags: c#, dll, appdomain

I have a dll written by someone else and that has many flaws. Let's assume there is only one class defined in this DLL. I need to import this DLL and create an instance of this class.
The DLL code might be the following :

```
   [Serializable()]
    public class makeExceptionClass
    {
        public bool isStringNormalized(string aString)
        {
            // A null check should be performed
            return aString.IsNormalized();
        }
    }
```

I wrote a small program to check whether or not my program can still run even if the dll crashes. The program is just a proof of concept. It takes two arguments, the first is used to load directly the DLL from an assembly and the second is used to provoke a crash.
The code of the program is the following :

```
class Program
{
    [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string typeOfLoading = args[0];
        string crash = args[1];

        // Load the DLL
        if (typeOfLoading.Equals("direct") == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Loading directly a DLL");
            Assembly anAssembly = Assembly.Load("unloadableDLL");    // Directly load the DLL
            unloadableDLL.makeExceptionClass anObject = (unloadableDLL.makeExceptionClass)anAssembly.CreateInstance("unloadableDLL.makeExceptionClass");

            if (crash.Equals("crash") == true)
            {
                bool test = anObject.isStringNormalized(null);
            }
            else
            {
                bool test = anObject.isStringNormalized("test");
            }
        }
        else if (typeOfLoading.Equals("indirect") == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Loading indirectly a DLL");
            AppDomain anAppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("RemoteLoaderDomain");   // Assume it does not fail;
            Type t = typeof(unloadableDLL.makeExceptionClass);
            unloadableDLL.makeExceptionClass anObject = (unloadableDLL.makeExceptionClass)anAppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap("unloadableDLL", t.FullName);

            if (crash.Equals("crash") == true)
            {
                bool test = anObject.isStringNormalized(null);
            }
            else
            {
                bool test = anObject.isStringNormalized("test");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Unloading the domain");
            AppDomain.Unload(anAppDomain);                
        }
        else
        {
            // don't care
        }

        // terminate
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The problem is that my program crashes regardless if the dll is loaded directly or into an AppDomain.
I am completely new to C# (I started this morning) but I have a C++ background.

Comment: What you mean by "crash"? An exception?

Comment: You might consider looking into MEF and/or MAF; both are frameworks that allow you to load potentially hostile or buggy third party code into an application and communicate with it over an established interface. More generally: you are attempting a task that is inherently difficult and that even experienced C# programmers find tricky. It is not what I would have chosen as someone's first day of C# coding, or even their 1000th day. Good luck!

Comment: Yep, I haven't really chosen it, I was kindly asked to do it by my boss :D

Comment: I would actually like to know the same thing, but slightly different. If the module/DLL  itself does something, and get an exception that isnt caught, the entire parent application/container crashes. So, lets assume a DLL starts a TcpListener, and clients connect to it. Then something happens with something that a client sent - then the container application crashes. I would like to know how I can handle those situations, so the container application does not crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add try / catch around your call:

```
  try
  {
    if (crash.Equals("crash") == true)
    {
      bool test = anObject.isStringNormalized(null);
    }
    else
    {
      bool test = anObject.isStringNormalized("test");
    }
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine("exception in dll call: "+ex);
  }
```

Comment: Hi. What is the purpose of the appDomain then ?

Comment: My guess is that a NullRef exception is not a crash. You get that exception and should handle it. A crash would be considered something illegal happened in unmanaged code like Access violation or Segment fault. Your logic would prevent that code in a DLL can throw you an exception at all.

Comment: Hi. I must clarify the problem : a team needs to test the communication through ethernet of a product. The Team uses NI TestStand to write tests.<br/>TestStand uses a DLL that I write but I don't have any control over testStand code. In my DLL, I have a member of a class B. This member of type B comes from a DLL (we'll call it DLLB) that I can't control because I'm not in charge of it.<br/> TestStand crashes because if an exception in DLLB. TestStand doesn't have try catch exception handling and it thinks it uses a DLLB through my B member.

Comment: This is why I need to isolate DLL B from my DLL and maintain a reference to B instantiated in another domain.

Comment: The crash that happens is an access violation. DLL B uses LibCurlNet. In some tests, two connections are opened in two separate threads I think. One connection can be disposed. Then, when trying to dispose the second connection, there is an access violation.

Comment: I think your code above to test that is not valid for this purpose as it throws a "regular" nullref exception from managed code.

Comment: But if there is somee uncaught exception in the loaded dll, but its not a direct call  from the "container application", how can I make sure the app doesnt die as a result of it?